# Create failed for Login 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE' ... User does not have permission to perform this action

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis

I am following the article from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674930/Configuring-IIS-ASP-NET-and-SQL-Server

to setup my database after I have setup my IIS. It works initially. I can run my web application successfully. But after I make some changes to the access right in for network service user, I hit error and when I go back to Security > Logins, I see only 3 users: Builtin/Users, sa and SteveNgai\User.

Now, I went to re-create back "Network Service" (Logins > New Login), I hit this error below. What should I do to fix this?

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Create failed for Login 'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=12.0.2000.8+((SQL14_RTM).140220-1752)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Create+Login&LinkId=20476

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

User does not have permission to perform this action. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15247)

Answer (score 0):

The user that you was using to create a new login simply does not have the required permissions.

Read [this page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx) that explains how to create a login in sql server.
Note the Security segment:

> Requires ALTER ANY LOGIN or ALTER LOGIN permission on the server.

Comment: I am using Window authentication.

Comment: the authentication method have nothing to do with that. the problem is that you are attempting to create a login while using a login that does not have the required permissions.